# iOS API for refilling prescriptions?

Tags: ios, api

I'm considering an iOS application that will allow a user to scan and refill Rx Prescriptions using their iPhone.

There are several iOS applications out there that do this now.  I'm wondering what type of APIs are available for me to work with to do the same.

Due to the nature of the task I'm sure they will commercial but that is fine.

Any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might be better off identifying the applications that do what you want your app to do and then ask how something specific in them is done.

Answer (score 3):

There is unlikely to be any such public API. You should check with the pharmacies you're planning to interoperate with, but chances are that it's simply not available, as there are some *extremely* stringent privacy requirements* surrounding all private health information in the US.

*: in particular, [HIPAA](http://www.hhs.gov/ocr/privacy/)

Comment: Yes, pharmacies are considered HIPPA covered entities; so you will be required to comply with federal HIPAA regulations.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I am very familiar with HIPAA requirements, and I'm certain the API won't be public or even free.  Given that so many applications exist today to do this (I counted at least 10 with a quick search), I have to imagine that there are quite a few vendors that I could work with.